# Phonegap, web-services logic?

Tags: javascript, html, web-services, cordova

I am wondering, if you had to describe or draw the logic behind calling a web service, while using, jQueryMobile, HTML5, CSS, Java-Script.

For example, in the Android platform. We have.

1.User Interface in an XML file, or Java

2.Behavior, in java classes. In those classes we have then all the behavior, connectivity and so on.

3.In the java class, we can write java code to interact with an external Web-service.

In a Mobile Web App we have

1. User interface, HTML,CSS,JS (include frameworks, jQueryMobile etc...)

How about the behavior?? I know JavaScript is for behavior, but is it used also to call web services, update, download, files, text and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, yes.

jQuery ajax is great for updating and downloading data in your html.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "update/user/",
  data: { name: "Daniel", location: "Sweden" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "response: " + msg );
  // set text area to msg etc..
});
```

For more inspiration, check out [google playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/)

Comment: So is this, similar as using, java, to call a web-service, in android for example, and then updating to the UI ? I am just trying to understand the whole logic behind is, since I am not good at web, but I have been doing native apps in Android.

Comment: Yes, ajax above is a HTTP POST to a webserver, and the server returns a response.  Also If the server returns json,  its makes everything much easier when parsing the response.

Comment: I am wondering, in a normal web-site with back-end, and front-end why we call web services through the JavaScript(client), wouldn't it be faster if the call to the web-serve, was made by the back end?

Comment: Always depend on the situation,  buy there are several pros with asynchronous calls in client.  One example is a webpage can load everything and show the user, then fill the data from slow webservice.

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback, I am getting the hung of it now. Tack